# Websocket rfile

Tags: python, websocket

Based on this [Websocket](https://gist.github.com/lostcoaster/3c5e287e7a6e151acde5) implementation.
In function send_message tested on Python 3.3 I got error:

```
self.request.send(chr(129))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I have added bytes function with utf-8 encoding:

```
    def send_message(self, message):
        self.request.send(bytes(chr(129), 'utf-8'))     
        length = len(message)
        if length <= 125:
            self.request.send(bytes(chr(length),'utf-8'))
        elif 126 <= length <= 65535:
            self.request.send(126)
            self.request.send(struct.pack(">H", length))
        else:
            self.request.send(127)
            self.request.send(struct.pack(">Q", length))
        self.request.send(bytes(message, 'utf-8'))
```

But in function on_message like this:

```
    def on_message(self, message):
        print(message)
        if message == 'ping':
            self.send_message("ping reply\r\n")
```

I got error:

```
  File "C:\tmp\py\server\my_server\TWebsocketHandler.py", line 36, in handle
    self.read_next_message()
  File "C:\tmp\py\server\my_server\TWebsocketHandler.py", line 42, in read_next_message
    length = self.rfile.read(2)[1] & 127  # rfile in rb mode
IndexError: index out of range
```

Why handle is triggered when rfile is empty ?
Anyone have idea how to correct this ?

Comment: should theline of the file in your link not be  `server = socketserver.TCPServer`

Comment: Can you explain ? This implementation is working only in one way, I can receive messages, but I can't send reply. But handshake is working correctly

Comment: I mean where is `SocketServer` defined in that code, it does not exist in the namespace